# Move directory without knowing name

Tags: linux, terminal, cp, mv

I have a directory with files and another directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 RORY  staff      102 Mar 29 05:07 FOLDER-XYZ123
drwx------+ 23 RORY  staff      782 Mar 29 04:19 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 RORY  staff  5000000 Mar 24 21:48 setup.part1.rar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 RORY  staff  1622537 Mar 24 21:48 setup.part2.rar
```

How can I move the FOLDER someplace else without actually knowing it's name? FOLDER-XYZ123 could be named anything, so I wouldn't know the name in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

`find $SOURCE_DIR -type d -exec mv -f {} $TARGET_DIR \;`